# The number of solutions of $x^{22} \equiv 2(mod23)$ has-

Tags: congruences, congruence-relations

Possible answers-

a).no solutions.

b).$23$ solutions.

c).exactly one solution.

d).$22$ solutions.

**Solution:** Since,$gcd(1,23)=23$ divides 2,so it has exactly one solution.

It seems i'm wrong because the concept which i've applied is for linear congrueces.

Don't know how to pursue this.

Is there any theorem generalizing this result?

Need help!

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee & Bill Dubuque,you both explained excellently,but i've just read that this problem is an application of Euler's theorem(let $m $ be a positive integer,and let $a$ be an integer relatively prime to $m$.Then-$a^{ \phi (m)} \equiv 1$($mod$ m)).

Comment: $(1,23)=1$ not $23$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ x\equiv 0\,$ is not a root, nor is any $\,x\not\equiv 0\,$ a root, since then  $\,x^{22}\equiv 1\,$ by little Fermat

Comment: :From your answer & my above comment can we concludee that $ x^{22}≡2(mod23)$ has no solution?

Comment: @PKStyles Yes, since for every integer $\,x\,$ either $\,x\equiv 0\,$ or $\,x\not\equiv 0,\,$ and we saw above that $\,x\,$ is not a root in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,23)=1$ using Fermat's Little Theorem,  $$x^{23-1}\equiv1\pmod{23}$$

and $$1\not\equiv2\pmod{23}$$

What if $(x,23)\ne1\iff23|x$?

Comment: :let $ (x,23) = d \neq 1 \implies$ the only possibility for $d$ is $23 \implies x=23$.So $x=23 $ is the only solution.Am i correct?

Comment: @PKStyles, $$x=23\implies x^{22}\equiv0\pmod{23}$$

Comment: :It means that the $x^{22} \equiv 2(mod 23)$ has no solution?